# Linq multiple join ,then GroupBy along with OrderBy , tried everything I could find

Tags: linq

```
var CartItemsGroup = (from Cart in db.BuyOnlineCartMasters // orderby this Cart.CartID descending 
    join CartDetails in db.BuyOnlineCartDetails 
        on Cart.CartID equals CartDetails.CartID

    join ProductMaster in db.tblBuyOnlineMasters.Where(x => x.CompanyID == CompanyID)
        on CartDetails.BuyOnlineID equals ProductMaster.BuyOnlineID

//I tried here did not work ,  orderby Cart.CartID descending

    select new { Cart.CartID, Cart.InvoiceNumber, ProductMaster.CompanyID,
    ProductMaster.Price, ProductMaster.Title, ProductMaster.OfferPrice, 
    CartDetails.SoldPrice, CartDetails.Qty, CartDetails.ShippingStatus, 
    CartDetails.DeliveryStatus, TotalAmt = (CartDetails.Qty * CartDetails.SoldPrice)}

    into x

//I tried here did not work, orderby x.CartID descending

//TODO: where conditions are not set for cart like payment paid etc
    group x by x.CartID)
    .ToList();
```

I want to order the result by the cartID , because of the groupby clause I am unable to get it done

[image: Screenshot of the output structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering needs to be **after** grouping.

To achieve your goal, replace

```
group x by x.CartID
```

with

```
group x by x.CartID into g
orderby g.Key descending
select g
```

Comment: how to do orderby on some other column, just in case for a reference

Comment: It depends whether you want to order the groups or group elements. Ordering the groups by columns that are not part of the key is not easy.

Answer (score 1):

First select your data then group by. That will work. A sample with my tables

```
from data in
    (from o in DB.GM_ORDER
        join g in DB.GM_ORDERITEMS on o.ORDERID equals g.ORDERID
        join i in DB.GM_ITEM on g.ITEMID equals i.ITEMID
    where o.ORDERID<=11160 /* or any other filter to be applied */
    orderby o.ORDERID descending, i.ITEMCODE ascending /* in your case ORDERID will be CARTID. Continue sorting within the ORDER/CART with a second parameter (in your case can be delivery status) */
    select new { o.ORDERID, i.ITEMCODE, g.ITEMID, Total = (g.CURR_PRICE * g.QTY) }
) select data
into x
group x by x.ORDERID
```

Comment: I hope this too work, I used the above one, thanks for the support

Comment: appreciate your comment @arunprasad

Comment: This trick works in LINQ to Objects, but not in other LINQ providers like LINQ to Entities.